# Создание таблиц EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Нужно создать следующие сущности:
Сотрудники
Фамилия : string
Имя : string
Отчество : string
Дата рождения : datetime
Пол : enum
Подразделение :  Ссылка на подразделение

Подразделения
Название : string
Руководитель : Ссылка на сотрудника

Т.е. в подразделении должен быть руководитель.
Пробую так, но не работает.

```
`public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string? Gender { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department? Department { get; set; }       

    public List<Order>? Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }


    public int DirectorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DirectorId")]
    public Employee? Director { get; set; }

    public List<Employee>? Employees { get; set; }
}`
```

Как правильно сделать? Спасёт только отдельная таблица?

Comment: `Пробую так, но не работает` что это значит?

Comment: При выполнении миграции выдаёт ошибку: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Department.Director' of type 'Employee'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: попробуйте пометить все `int Id` как `[Key]`, а также `public Department?`, `public List<Order>?`, `public Employee?` и `public List<Employee>?` как `virtual`

Comment: @iiKuzmychov `[Key]` - нет такого атрибута, `virtual` - не помог.

Comment: [есть](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute?view=net-7.0) такой аттрибут

Comment: @iiKuzmychov да точно есть)), но не помогло, возможно настройка через Fluent Api поможет, осталось понять, что это за настройка